# Malsup jQuery form upload in chunks

Tags: jquery, chunked

I use the malsup jQuery form with upload. It works with PHP. http://malsup.com/jquery/form/

Is there a nice way to add chunked uploads using malsup? Any suggestions?

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

```
    var percent = $('.percent');
    var bar = $('.bar');

    /* submit form with ajax request */
    $('form').ajaxForm({

        dataType: 'json',


        beforeSend: function() {
            bar.width('0%');
            percent.html('0%');
        },

        uploadProgress: function(event, position, total, percentComplete) {
            var pVel = percentComplete + '%';
            bar.width(pVel);
            percent.html(pVel);
        },


        success: function(xhr) {
            var percentVal = '100%';
            bar.width(percentVal)
            percent.html(percentVal);
        },

        complete: function(xhr) {
            var url = window.location.origin = window.location.protocol+"//"+window.location.host+"/thank-you/";
            window.location.replace(url);
        }



    });
```

EDIT: Has anyone else experienced that the upload bar indicator is not working on mobile Chrome (at least it's not working on Chrome for iOS and I have tested with their default examples as well)?

Kind regards
Johan